# How to apply a function to each element of a list or vector in Clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I see that the map function exists in Clojure, but I don't understand how to refer to each element in the list. Not sure if it is possible. In Ruby, I would write something like this:

```
list_of_numbers = [1,2,3]
list_of_numbers.map {|num| num * 2}
```

can I do something like that with the map function in Clojure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(def nums [1 2 3])
(def doubles (mapv #(* % 2) nums))   ; or just `map`
(println doubles)

=> [2 4 6]
```

For a good start, see:

- http://braveclojure.com
- [Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)
- books like [Getting Clojure](https://pragprog.com/book/roclojure/getting-clojure)
- http://clojure.org